# Moving the field editor

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an `NSTableView` subclass with a little animation on it that sometimes changes the width of its columns. It works fine, but if one of the cells is being edited at the time, the field editor stays where it is and does not match the new frame of the cell as it is resized. Whenever I animate the columns, I call the following function in the `NSTableView` subclass:

```
- (void) updateFieldEditorPosition {
    if([self editedRow]!= -1 && [self editedColumn] != -1) {
        NSText *fieldEditor = [[self window] fieldEditor:NO forObject:self];
        NSRect editedCellFrame = [self frameOfCellAtColumn:[self editedColumn] row:[self editedRow]];
        if(!NSEqualRects([fieldEditor frame], editedCellFrame)) {
            [fieldEditor setFrame:editedCellFrame];
            [fieldEditor setNeedsDisplay:YES];
            [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to do anything. I have checked that I am, indeed, receiving the correct field editor, and through the debugger I can see that the field editor's frame *is* being set to the right value and changes over time, but it never actually *moves* on-screen. What am I missing?

---

**EDIT:**
So, I've made an interesting discovery. If, at the same time that I set the `NSTableColumn`'s width, I also set it as hidden and then unhide it again, the field editor moves along with it!

```
[tableColumn setWidth:newWidth];
[tableColumn setHidden:YES];
[tableColumn setHidden:NO];
```

I don't know what boolean is getting flipped when I set the `NSTableColumn` as hidden, but it's working and the field editor is updating itself. It's not the `NSTableView`'s needsDisplay, because if I set that instead of hiding the column nothing happens. Can anyone explain this to me so I can do it a little more elegantly?